# ipv6 static routing is not working

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6

wondering ipv6 static route default route nothing working, only can ping the directly connected interface, but sh run command gave the static routes which I created to other networks, but on the sh run output I saw the autoconfig static route which I created to obtain global unicast addresses and on the next line I saw the static route which i created to reach remote network, Any ideas? I cant see any successful ping to remote network

I give more information
3 routers in a row, routerA, routerB, routerC, connected via fastethernet. middle router B had it's ipv6 address configured manually and other two routes receive global unicast address through ipv6 address autoconfig command

here is the "Sh run" output of router A

```
version 12.4
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption 
!

hostname Router
!

! 
!

!
!

ipv6 unicast-routing
!

!
!

!
!

!
!

!
! 

!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!

!
!

!
interface FastEthernet0/0
no ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
ipv6 address autoconfig
ipv6 enable
!

interface FastEthernet0/1
no ip address 
duplex auto
speed auto
shutdown
!

interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
!

ip classless
!

ipv6 route 2001:DB6:3C4D:1::/64 FastEthernet0/0 FE80::200:CFF:FE4A:AC01
ipv6 route 2001:DB6:3C4D:2::/64 FastEthernet0/0
```

THE SH RUN OUTPUT OF ROUTER C

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 660 bytes
!

version 12.4
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!

hostname Router
!

!
!

!
!

ipv6 unicast-routing
!  

!
!

!
!

!
!

!
!

!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!

!
!

!
interface FastEthernet0/0
no ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
ipv6 address autoconfig
ipv6 enable
!

interface FastEthernet0/1
no ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
shutdown  
!

interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
!

ip classless
!

ipv6 route 2001:DB6:3C4D:2::/64 FastEthernet0/0 FE80::200:CFF:FE4A:AC02
ipv6 route 2001:DB6:3C4D:1::/64 FastEthernet0/0
!

!
!

!
!

!
line con 0
!

line aux 0
!

line vty 0 4
login
!

!
!

end
```

Router A routing table

```
Router#sh ipv6 route 
IPv6 Routing Table - 4 entries
Codes: C - Connected, L - Local, S - Static, R - RIP, B - BGP  
U - Per-user Static route, M - MIPv6
I1 - ISIS L1, I2 - ISIS L2, IA - ISIS interarea, IS - ISIS summary   
O - OSPF intra, OI - OSPF inter, OE1 - OSPF ext 1, OE2 - OSPF ext 2
ON1 - OSPF NSSA ext 1, ON2 - OSPF NSSA ext 2
D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external
C 2001:DB6:3C4D:1::/64 [0/0]
via ::, FastEthernet0/0
L   2001:DB6:3C4D:1:260:5CFF:FEA8:3A01/128 [0/0]
via ::, FastEthernet0/0
S 2001:DB6:3C4D:2::/64 [1/0]
via ::, FastEthernet0/0
L FF00::/8 [0/0] 
via ::, Null0
Router#
```

router C routing table

```
Router#sh ipv6 route 
IPv6 Routing Table - 4 entries
Codes: C - Connected, L - Local, S - Static, R - RIP, B - BGP 
U - Per-user Static route, M - MIPv6
I1 - ISIS L1, I2 - ISIS L2, IA - ISIS interarea, IS - ISIS summary
O - OSPF intra, OI - OSPF inter, OE1 - OSPF ext 1, OE2 - OSPF ext 2
ON1 - OSPF NSSA ext 1, ON2 - OSPF NSSA ext 2   
D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external
S 2001:DB6:3C4D:1::/64 [1/0] 
via ::, FastEthernet0/0
C 2001:DB6:3C4D:2::/64 [0/0]
via ::, FastEthernet0/0
L 2001:DB6:3C4D:2:290:CFF:FE49:7601/128 [0/0]
via ::, FastEthernet0/0
L FF00::/8 [0/0]
via ::, Null0
```

there static route is defined and why it's not pinging!

middle router B configuration

```
Router#sh run
Building configuration..

Current configuration : 590 bytes
!

version 12.4
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption 
!

hostname Router
!

!
!

!
!

ipv6 unicast-routing
!

!
!

!
!

!
!

!
!

!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!

!
!

!
interface FastEthernet0/0
no  ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
ipv6 address 2001:DB6:3C4D:1::1/64  
ipv6 enable
!   

interface FastEthernet0/1
no ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
ipv6 address 2001:DB6:3C4D:2::1/64
ipv6 enable   
! 

interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
!

ip classless
!

!
!

!
!

!
!

line con 0
!  

line aux 0
!

line vty 0 4
login
!

!
!

end
```

why router A and C are not pinging?

thanks for the answear  , I disable one static route for a directly connected interface ,still it's pinging it's directly connected neighbor only, when I tried from router C to router b ,not even pinging the remote exit interface of router B to router A, here I provide the sh run output of router C after configuration change

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 588 bytes
! 
version 12.4
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
! 
ipv6 unicast-routing 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
no ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
ipv6 address autoconfig
ipv6 enable
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
shutdown  
!
ip classless
!
ipv6 route 2001:DB6:3C4D:1::/64 FastEthernet0/0
!
!
```

routing table on C

```
Router#sh ipv6 route 
IPv6 Routing Table - 4 entries
Codes: C - Connected, L - Local, S - Static, R - RIP, B - BGP
   U - Per-user Static route, M - MIPv6
   I1 - ISIS L1, I2 - ISIS L2, IA - ISIS interarea, IS - ISIS summary
   O - OSPF intra, OI - OSPF inter, OE1 - OSPF ext 1, OE2 - OSPF ext 2
   ON1 - OSPF NSSA ext 1, ON2 - OSPF NSSA ext 2
   D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external
S   2001:DB6:3C4D:1::/64 [1/0]
 via ::, FastEthernet0/0
C   2001:DB6:3C4D:2::/64 [0/0]
 via ::, FastEthernet0/0
L   2001:DB6:3C4D:2:290:CFF:FE49:7601/128 [0/0]
 via ::, FastEthernet0/0
L   FF00::/8 [0/0]
 via ::, Null0
```

Comment: This question looks platform specific. Could you please tag it with the name of the routing platform you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret the configuration correctly, you tell neither router A nor router C that they should use router B to reach the respective other network (`via 2001:DB6:3C4D:1::1`, resp. `via 2001:DB6:3C4D:2::1` instead of `via ::`). In fact, you configured A and C with *both* networks `2001:DB6:3C4D:1::/64` and `2001:DB6:3C4D:2::/64` on their respective local link.

Comment: thank u, changed the configuration still not pinging, see the bottom on answearfor editted answear